# How do I optimize calculating the hash of thousands of files?

Tags: c#, .net, file, hash

I have a .Net program that runs through a directory containing tens of thousands of relatively small files (around 10MB each), calculates their MD5 hash and stores that data in an SQLite database. The whole process works fine, however it takes a relatively long time (1094353ms with around 60 thousand files) and I'm looking for ways to optimize it. Here are the solutions I've thought of:

1. Use additional threads and calculate the hash of more than one file simultaneously. Not sure how I/O speed would limit me with this one.
2. Use a better hashing algorithm. I've looked around and the one I'm currently using seems to be the fastest one (on C# at least).

Which would be the best approach, and are there any better ones?

Here's my current code:

```
private async Task<string> CalculateHash(string file, System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5) {
    Task<string> MD5 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        {
            using (var stream = new BufferedStream(System.IO.File.OpenRead(file), 1200000))
                {
                    var hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
                    var fileMD5 = string.Concat(Array.ConvertAll(hash, x => x.ToString("X2")));

                    return fileMD5;
                }
            };
        });

        return await MD5;
    }

public async Main() {
    using (var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create()) {
         foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path)) {
            var hash = await CalculateHash(file, md5);

            // Adds `hash` to the database
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `1094353ms with around 60 thousand files` ....that's an odd significant digit style ;-)

Comment: When you think of it like that it's really not very significant, but considering a big part of the files don't even break 200 KB in size, I think there's some optimization to be done.

Comment: The IO can be quite a hurdle. Maybe it's best to measure the IO-load first to determine if this is a bottleneck. Having said that, this seems (to me) a typical 1 time operation. Are you sure you want to optimize it that far?

Comment: You're right, this is a one-time operation, however it'd be great to not have to make the user wait 18 minutes when launching my program for the first time :P I'm gonna monitor the I/O load to see if that's bottlenecking and report back.

Comment: These kind of things typically runs on the background. Things like music players or randsomewarez XD tend to let you use the program while background indexing takes place.

Comment: Makes sense, but sadly the program relies heavily on this database being in place to do it's thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a pipeline of work, the easiest way I know how to create a pipeline that uses both parts of the code that must be single threaded and parts that must be multi-threaded is to use [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library)

```
public static class Example
{ 
    private class Dto
    {
        public Dto(string filePath, byte[] data)
        {
            FilePath = filePath;
            Data = data;
        }

        public string FilePath { get; }
        public byte[] Data { get; }
    }

    public static async Task ProcessFiles(string path)
    {
        var getFilesBlock = new TransformBlock<string, Dto>(filePath => new Dto(filePath, File.ReadAllBytes(filePath))); //Only lets one thread do this at a time.

        var hashFilesBlock = new TransformBlock<Dto, Dto>(dto => HashFile(dto), 
                new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount, //We can multi-thread this part.
                                                  BoundedCapacity = 50}); //Only allow 50 byte[]'s to be waiting in the queue. It will unblock getFilesBlock once there is room.

        var writeToDatabaseBlock = new ActionBlock<Dto>(WriteToDatabase,
              new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {BoundedCapacity = 50});//MaxDegreeOfParallelism defaults to 1 so we don't need to specifiy it.

        //Link the blocks together.
        getFilesBlock.LinkTo(hashFilesBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true});
        hashFilesBlock.LinkTo(writeToDatabaseBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true});

        //Queue the work for the first block.
        foreach (var filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
        {
            await getFilesBlock.SendAsync(filePath).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        //Tell the first block we are done adding files.
        getFilesBlock.Complete();

        //Wait for the last block to finish processing its last item.
        await writeToDatabaseBlock.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private static Dto HashFile(Dto dto)
    {
        using (var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
        {
            return new Dto(dto.FilePath, md5.ComputeHash(dto.Data));
        }
    }

    private static async Task WriteToDatabase(Dto arg)
    {
        //Write to the database here.
    }
}
```

This creates a pipeline with 3 segments.

One that is single threaded that reads the files from the hard drive in to memory and stored as a `byte[]`.

A second one that can use up to `Enviorement.ProcessorCount` threads to hash the files, it will only allow 50 items to be sitting on it's inbound queue, when the first block tries to add it will stop processing new items until the next block is ready to accept new items.

And a third one that is single threaded and adds the data to the database, it allows only 50 items in it's inbound queue at a time.

Because of the two 50 limits there will be at most 100 `byte[]` in memory (50 in `hashFilesBlock` queue, 50 in the `writeToDatabaseBlock` queue, items currently being processed count toward the `BoundedCapacity` limit.

---

**Update**: for fun I wrote a version that reports progress too, it's untested though and uses C# 7 features.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

public static class Example
{
    private class Dto
    {
        public Dto(string filePath, byte[] data)
        {
            FilePath = filePath;
            Data = data;
        }

        public string FilePath { get; }
        public byte[] Data { get; }
    }

    public static async Task ProcessFiles(string path, IProgress<ProgressReport> progress)
    {
        int totalFilesFound = 0;
        int totalFilesRead = 0;
        int totalFilesHashed = 0;
        int totalFilesUploaded = 0;

        DateTime lastReported = DateTime.UtcNow;

        void ReportProgress()
        {
            if (DateTime.UtcNow - lastReported < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) //Try to fire only once a second, but this code is not perfect so you may get a few rapid fire.
            {
                return;
            }
            lastReported = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var report = new ProgressReport(totalFilesFound, totalFilesRead, totalFilesHashed, totalFilesUploaded);
            progress.Report(report);
        }


        var getFilesBlock = new TransformBlock<string, Dto>(filePath =>
        {
            var dto = new Dto(filePath, File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
            totalFilesRead++; //safe because single threaded.
            return dto;
        });

        var hashFilesBlock = new TransformBlock<Dto, Dto>(inDto =>
            {
                using (var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
                {
                    var outDto = new Dto(inDto.FilePath, md5.ComputeHash(inDto.Data));
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref totalFilesHashed); //Need the interlocked due to multithreaded.
                    ReportProgress();
                    return outDto;
                }
            },
            new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount, BoundedCapacity = 50});

        var writeToDatabaseBlock = new ActionBlock<Dto>(arg =>
            {
                //Write to database here.
                totalFilesUploaded++;
                ReportProgress();
            },
            new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {BoundedCapacity = 50});

        getFilesBlock.LinkTo(hashFilesBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true});
        hashFilesBlock.LinkTo(writeToDatabaseBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true});

        foreach (var filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
        {
            await getFilesBlock.SendAsync(filePath).ConfigureAwait(false);
            totalFilesFound++;
            ReportProgress();
        }

        getFilesBlock.Complete();

        await writeToDatabaseBlock.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false);
        ReportProgress();
    }
}

public class ProgressReport
{
    public ProgressReport(int totalFilesFound, int totalFilesRead, int totalFilesHashed, int totalFilesUploaded)
    {
        TotalFilesFound = totalFilesFound;
        TotalFilesRead = totalFilesRead;
        TotalFilesHashed = totalFilesHashed;
        TotalFilesUploaded = totalFilesUploaded;
    }

    public int TotalFilesFound { get; }
    public int TotalFilesRead{ get; }
    public int TotalFilesHashed{ get; }
    public int TotalFilesUploaded{ get; }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's super fast. It was around 4 minutes faster than my implementation. I'll definitely use this (and take a look at Dataflow). Thanks!

Comment: Computing multiple file hashes might be faster in CUDA using NVIDIA GPUs... It is a classic CUDA solution.

Comment: I tried the original version here and it throws exception on the line:
var getFilesBlock = new TransformBlock<string, Dto>(filePath => new Dto(filePath, File.ReadAllBytes(filePath))); //Only lets one thread do this at a time.
Reporting that a file is used by another process... Enclosing this is exception handling does not work either...still bombs with unhandled exception...

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand, Task.Run will instantiate a new thread for every file you have there, which leads to lots of threads and context switching between them. The case like you describe, sounds like a good case for using Parallel.For or Parallel.Foreach, something like this:

```
public void CalcHashes(string path)
{
    string GetFileHash(System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5, string fileName)
    {
        using (var stream = new BufferedStream(System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName), 1200000))
        {
            var hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
            var fileMD5 = string.Concat(Array.ConvertAll(hash, x => x.ToString("X2")));

            return fileMD5;
        }
    }

    ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
    options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8;

    Parallel.ForEach(filenames, options, fileName =>
    {
        using (var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
        {
            GetFileHash(md5, fileName);
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT: Seems Parallel.ForEach does not actually do the partitioning automatically. Added max degree of parallelism limit to 8. As a result:
107005 files
46628 ms

Comment: In general running multiple I/O operations in parallel make things slower. Unless you know  for sure problem has bottleneck somewhere else suggesting to run multiple reads in parallel is not going to help.

Comment: Gonna benchmark this just in case. I'll report back with the results.

Comment: Already did, seems Alexei was right, parallel foreach was actually making things slower:)

Comment: Ah, that sucks. Thanks for the suggestion anyways o/

Comment: Edited the answer. Seems you have to explicitly limit the number of threads it creates, for Parallel.ForEach. With that limit, it is actually quite a bit faster than a) simple unthreaded version and b) spawn a thread for each iteration version.

Comment: That's odd, even after limiting to 8 threads I got 1400000ms scanning over the same directory

Comment: Well, later I experimented some more, with smaller set of files (ca 22k). Singlethreaded version ran approx 17300 ms. Multithreaded runs were about 7500 ms. A bit more than 2x faster. Didn't see much improvement past 4 threads. Then again, as I used the same files over again, they were all in system cache..