# Implementing ProgressBar Reporting with TPL Parallel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have very fast MD5 file hashing class found here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46516878/12854214) **(credits to the author!)** making use of TPL parallel Dataflow.

How can I *report hashing progress* to my UI - progressBar1.Value (Form1 control)?

I have tried everything, while it reports integers, I want to read hashing progress per process through the getter Progress. I have tried lots of things, but I get different readings from 0 - filecount.

```
    public static class Example
    {
        private class Dto
        {
            public Dto(string filePath, byte[] data)
            {
                FilePath = filePath;
                Data = data;
            }

            public string FilePath { get; }
            public byte[] Data { get; }
        }

        public static async Task ProcessFiles(string path, IProgress<ProgressReport> progress)
        {
            int totalFilesFound = 0;
            int totalFilesRead = 0;
            int totalFilesHashed = 0;
            int totalFilesUploaded = 0;
            int progressBar = 0;

            DateTime lastReported = DateTime.UtcNow;

            void ReportProgress()
            {
                if (DateTime.UtcNow - lastReported < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) // Try to fire only once a second, but this code is not perfect so you may get a few rapid fire.
                {
                    return;
                }

                lastReported = DateTime.UtcNow;

                var report = new ProgressReport(totalFilesFound, totalFilesRead, totalFilesHashed, totalFilesUploaded, progressBar);
                progress.Report(report);

            }


            // We need to aim for this per instance!
            //  int progress = (int)((double)totalBytesRead / size * 100);


            /*

            TaskScheduler uiTaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

            // Create ActionBlock for progressBar
            var progressBlock = new ActionBlock<Dto>(arg => new ActionBlock<int>((n) =>
            {
                progressBar = Math.Min(Math.Max(0, n), 100);

            }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
            {
                TaskScheduler = uiTaskScheduler
            }));

            */


            var getFilesBlock = new TransformBlock<string, Dto>(filePath =>
            {
                var dto = new Dto(filePath, File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
                totalFilesRead++; // Safe because single threaded.
                return dto;
            });

            var hashFilesBlock = new TransformBlock<Dto, Dto>(inDto =>
            {
                using var md5 = MD5.Create();
                var outDto = new Dto(inDto.FilePath, md5.ComputeHash(inDto.Data));
                Interlocked.Increment(ref totalFilesHashed); // Need the interlocked due to multithreaded.
                ReportProgress();
                return outDto;
            }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount,
                BoundedCapacity = 50
            });

            var writeToDatabaseBlock = new ActionBlock<Dto>(arg =>
            {
                // Write to database here.
                totalFilesUploaded++;
                ReportProgress();
            }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                BoundedCapacity = 50
            });

            getFilesBlock.LinkTo(hashFilesBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions
            {
                PropagateCompletion = true
            });

            hashFilesBlock.LinkTo(writeToDatabaseBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions
            {
                PropagateCompletion = true
            });

            // Start looping paths
            foreach (var filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
            {
                await getFilesBlock.SendAsync(filePath).ConfigureAwait(false);
                totalFilesFound++;
                ReportProgress();
            }

            getFilesBlock.Complete();

            await writeToDatabaseBlock.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false);

        }
    }

    public class ProgressReport
    {
        public ProgressReport(int totalFilesFound, int totalFilesRead, int totalFilesHashed, int totalFilesUploaded, int progressBar)
        {
            TotalFilesFound = totalFilesFound;
            TotalFilesRead = totalFilesRead;
            TotalFilesHashed = totalFilesHashed;
            TotalFilesUploaded = totalFilesUploaded;
            Progress = progressBar;
        }

        public int TotalFilesFound { get; }
        public int TotalFilesRead { get; }
        public int TotalFilesHashed { get; }
        public int TotalFilesUploaded { get; }

        public int Progress { get; }

    }
```

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Read progress values and send to control
   IProgress<ProgressReport> progress = new Progress<ProgressReport>(value => {
      progressBar1.Value = value.Progress;
   });

   await Example.ProcessFiles(@".\Downloads", progress);
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

.NET Framework 4.8

Comment: Not clear what *I want to read hashing progress per process through the getter Progress*. Do you want to report Progress each time a new file is read, to notify the sum of the all the bytes read to this point in time? The getter procedure is single-threaded, just sum the `dto.Data.Length` parts after `var dto = new Dto(filePath, File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));`-- If this is the intent, to have a consistent progress using a ProgressBar, you have to know the overall size of all the files you're hashing. Make the computation on the UI-Thread side, not the async proc side

Comment: Its funny you mentioned that about dto.Data.Length, thats just what I went for and implemented in before reading your reply, will report back how it goes

Comment: If you instead want to compute the overall size of the hashed files, perform the sum in `hashFilesBlock()`

Comment: ``int Progress(int size) { progressBar = Interlocked.Add(ref progressBar, 1); return progressBar * 100 / size; }`` gets me further

Comment: I have this completely implemented with multiple progress / threads and computes fast (but terrible on I/O without a large buffer), but is a separate Task on my main Form1 so I got into the TPL business and here I am. Im realizing, I have no clue what to do about this other than a sum and a set to ``progressValue`` setter, and it certainly raises the question on how to deal with multi progress control casts sending these values by key within a Listview in parallel - which my current Task does perfectly other than terrible Disk performance.